# Can I set the width of a div block depending on it's height?

Tags: html, css, height, width

Is there any way that I can set the width of a div block depending on it's height?

As example, I have a block of which's height depends on the parent and I want to set its width depending on its height.

Comment: only by javascript

Comment: not with just css. You will need javascript, or calculate it with server-side code (though the latter would require it to be a fixed size that you know before render)

Comment: With css, you can only set a ratio depending on height or width, but for more you will need javascript. Check this link : http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Answer (score -1):

Here is a trick to do that, where you can add a image with 1:1 in the child

```css
.parent {
    height: 250px;
}

.child {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background:#333;
}

.child img {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x350/ffffff/ffffff" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: of course you can check by increasing the parents height

Answer (score -1):

I would use width and height relative to window width. Like so:

Div{
  Width: 50vw;
  Height: 
}